# How do you start a background process in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl

I'm trying to figure out how to start a background process in a perl script (on Windows). In other words, I don't want the script to wait for the child process to complete before regaining control. Is there an easy way to do this in just a few lines of code? I've looked at perldoc for the system command, but it doesn't seem to do what I want..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See system in [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#system): "`system(1,@args)` spawns an external process and immediately returns its process designator, without waiting for it to terminate...(Win32)"

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest solution posted here. Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Win32::Job](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Job-0.04/Job.pm).