# Video stuck on system(1, @commands) in Perl script

Tags: windows, perl, system, media, windows-media-player

I'm trying to write a Perl script that runs videos in a directory `n` times on Windows Media Player one after the other.

For some reason, on the 64th video playing, it gets stuck on `system(1, @commands)`.

Right now, the command is `system(1, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer", $path);` in the following for-loop.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
    # do stuff

    # Play video
    system(1, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer", $path);

    sleep $duration + 1;

    # do stuff
}
```

I'm wondering why it keeps stopping at the 64th video (I've run this multiple times and it's always the 64th.) Maybe someone can explain `system(1, @commands)` better to me? All I know is that it just doesn't wait for `@commands` to finish before continuing the program...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: btw, $path is the path of the video I want to play. thanks!

Comment: What does the first arguement `1` mean? I'd expect that to try to execute a command named `1`, but it does seem to do *something* on Windows. `perldoc -f system` doesn't seem to mention it. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Yeah.. that's what I'm not sure of myself. I've only seen it on forums.. like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481986/how-do-you-start-a-background-process-in-perl

Comment: See my comments on Annjawn's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've reached the maximum number of child processes you can have running simultaneously. Reap those that have completed using [`waitpid`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html).

---

Alternatively, if you don't care about the process's exit code, you might have better luck with

```
system(qq{start /b "" "c:\...\wmplayer" "$path"});
```

Comment: would `waitpid` actually wait for the process to finish? because Windows Media Player doesn't terminate until I use "taskkill" or I manually close the window myself. Thanks for the explanation! =] 

I also found out that VLC player has -way- more command line support so I ended up using that instead and it is working great so far!

Comment: Depends on the 2nd argument you pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the help everybody!

I found out that VLC player has way more command line support than Windows Media Player and that it has exactly what I need:

```
vlc --play-and-exit $path
```

I stopped using `system(1,@commands)` and I'm just using regular old `system(@commands)` and everything seems to be working well so far! =]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
system(command,@args)
```

or

```
@args=("command","arg1","arg2"); 
system(@args);
```

In your case the command is `1`, not sure what it means. Rather try

```
system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe", $path);
```

Here, the command is the `.exe` (or the binary) which takes the video path(s) as arguments.

**UPDATE**: Based on comments

```
system(1,"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe", $path);
```

should work. Play the 64th video normally to check if it works and or reconfigure the sequence of videos and see if its still the 64th video causing problem.

Comment: Actually a first argument of `1` is a Win32-specific feature. It's not mentioned in `perldoc -f system`, but it's in `perldoc perlport`: As an optimization, may not call the command shell specified in `$ENV{PERL5SHELL}`. "`system(1, @args)`" spawns an external process and immediately returns its process designator, without waiting for it to terminate. Return value may be used subsequently in `wait` or `waitpid`. Failure to `spawn()` a subprocess is indicated by setting `$?` to `255 << 8`.

Comment: [continued]  `$?` is set in a way compatible with Unix (i.e. the exitstatus of the subprocess is obtained by `$? >> 8`, as described in the documentation).

Comment: `\ ` and `/` are equivalent here. If one doesn't work, neither will the other. If anything `\ ` would have a better chance of working. Please delete.

Comment: \ is used to escape special characters in this case \ itself. So rather to be specific \\ is similar to / in this case, but there is no substantial authenticity of the statement the "one might work better than the other".

Comment: System calls accept both. Command don't always. try `dir /` at the console.

Comment: Either way, you're arguing there is no difference, so why suggest the change!?